# Artificial Neural Network programming in C#

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have read lots of books, sites, and so about ANN programming, but I still have problems for writing a program in c# about that.

Many of these books and other sources are in Matlab and other languages, but I searched for C#

I read, for example, this book:

"[Introduction to Neural Networks for C#, 2nd Edition Paperback by Jeff Heaton](http://www.heatonresearch.com/book/programming-neural-networks-cs-2.html)"

and also these sits:

- http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/AI_OOP_NeuralNet06192006090112AM/AI_OOP_NeuralNet.aspx

Now my clear question is this :
How can I build a network and link all neuron together in layers[?](http://pooriahaddad.com/)

Comment: Where is the code you have written?

Comment: Have a look at these sites: [AForge.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16859/AForge-NET-open-source-framework) and [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/). They also provide examples that might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I have already read it all `"Introduction to Neural Networks for C#, 2nd Edition Paperback by Jeff Heaton"`.i think this book explain of all your question clearly.

nerves created with single dimension matrix and communication between fist layer and hidden layer stored in a two dimension and so on.so you have to read chapter first and second again and

### write its example your self.

You will get the concept.

Comment: I read this book about 4 years ago,first time i did not got it,so i write it's example and i got it's concepts. Movafagh bashid

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely look at the [Heaton Research](http://www.heatonresearch.com/) if you're up to write neural networks in C#. They already did it (they call it Encog) and the [source code is open](https://code.google.com/p/encog-cs/downloads/list).